# Cant use WebAuthenificationBroker due to convertibility error

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to make an app that connects to Facebook in Visual Studio Express. The problem is that in this piece  of code:

```
Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Result WebAuthenticationResult = WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                        WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                        StartUri,
                                                        EndUri);
```

... I think I have implemented the method as shown in the samples but I keep getting the following error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation'
>   to
>   'Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationResult' R:\Users\JesúsAndres\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\FBook\FBook\MainPage.xaml.cs 41  99  FBook

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AuthenticateAsync method doesn't return the authentication result directly but an IAsyncOperation.
You can use the `await` keyword in C# to make the asynchronous call synchronous.

```
Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Result WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, StartUri, EndUri);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx for further information.